# Redirect to Full domain name by enter alias name in the browser

Tags: reactjs, dns, azure-web-app-service, alias, cname

We have a react js frontend application hosted on azure app service(linux) running in a domain path

https://aliasname.subdomain.domain.com

We wanted to achieve accessing the application by just entering aliasname/ in the browser and it redirects to the full domain path - only on the intranet.

aliasname/ --> https://aliasname.subdomain.domain.com

The DNS changes are made on the DNS intranet server. aliasname pointing to full domain path.

But the desired output is not achieved. please advise if i am missing anything here or do I need to make any changes on the router ?